# Ejecución sin definir constructores C++

Tags: c++, c++11

una consulta.

Hice un pequeño código que muestra los valores que toman los datos de un objeto, sin inicializarlos en el main o mediante algún constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Cuenta{
private:
  int saldo;
  float interes;
  string nombre;
public:
  int obtenerSaldo(){return saldo;}
  float obtenerInteres(){return interes;}
  string obtenerNombre(){return nombre;}
};

int main(){

  Cuenta cuenta1;
  Cuenta cuenta2;
  cout << "Cuenta 1: " << cuenta1.obtenerSaldo() << " - " << cuenta1.obtenerInteres() << " - " << cuenta1.obtenerNombre() << endl;
  cout << "Cuenta 2: " << cuenta2.obtenerSaldo() << " - " << cuenta2.obtenerInteres() << " - " << cuenta2.obtenerNombre() << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Tengo entendido que a excepción del string, los otros datos no los inicializa con ningún valor en particular, sino con "basura". 
La ejecución de la Cuenta1 me da valores por completo aleatorios (Salvo el string, que siempre es vacío), sin embargo, Cuenta2 me da siempre la misma salida **2 - 0 -** . Mismo si comento la salida de Cuenta1, me sigue dando los mismos valores. 
Es por algo en especial que se da esto, o pura casualidad que hayan salido este tipo de valores?

Espero que se haya entendido. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Es por algo en especial que se da esto, o pura casualidad que hayan salido este tipo de valores?

Es pura casualidad debido, probablemente, al código generado por el compilador.

La memoria no se crea ni se destruye, se reutiliza. Cuando ejecutas un programa, ese programa usa la memoria como espacio de trabajo, escribiendo y leyendo valores. Después el programa se cierra... pero los valores siguen ahí, en la memoria.

Cuando se ejecuta un segundo programa, debe inicializar la memoria porque si no lo que se encontrará serán los valores dejados ahí por una aplicación anterior.

Este mecanismo se reproduce también dentro de un programa. Cuando una variable se sale de ámbito el programa libera la memoria asociada a dicha variable. Así la siguiente variable que se crea *hereda* esa región de memoria, luego si no la inicializa, se encontrará con los valores que dejase ahí la variable anterior.

> La ejecución de la Cuenta1 me da valores por completo aleatorios (Salvo el string, que siempre es vacío)

El `string` **siempre** te va a dar vacío. La clase `std::string` implementa un constructor que inicializa su estado interno, justamente lo que tu estás omitiendo en tu ejemplo. De ahí que los objetos de tipo `string` **siempre** empiecen estando vacios y no con contenido aleatorio.

Otro gallo cantaría si en vez de usar esta clase se usasen arrays *crudos* a la vieja usanza de C:

```
char* ptr[10];
std::cout << ptr; // Imprimirá basura y puede que el programa muera
```

El comentario del código lo dice todo... pero, espera... ¿Por qué dice que el programa puede morir?

La razón se encuentra en la gestión que hace de la memoria el Sistema Operativo. Los Sistemas Operativos modernos suelen controlar los accesos a memoria para evitar que un proceso pueda modificar memoria que no le pertenece, ya que esto provocaría que otros procesos (incluso los del propio sistema operativo), funcionasen de forma incorrecta.

Así, cuando el Sistema Operativo detecta que un programa intenta acceder a memoria que no le pertenece, lo que hace es matar el proceso para evitar que corrompa la memoria.

¿Y por qué iba a suceder esto con ese ejemplo tan tonto?

Bueno, `cout` escupirá caracteres en la consola hasta que se encuentre un terminador de cadena `'\0'`... si da la casualidad de que no se encuentra ninguno en la región de memoria asignada al programa, `cout` intentará entonces acceder a memoria que no le pertenece al programa y eso desencadenará el fallo del programa

Answer (score 1):

La no inicialización de variables en C++ es un comportamiento no definido. Esto quiere decir que el compilador es libre de elegir como crear el código de esta aplicación. Bajo un compilador tu aplicación puede generar una excepción por pisar memoria o puede crashear, mientras que otro puede inicializar variables basura o siempre con el mismo valor, como con otro compilador puede funcionar sin problemas. Esto aplica también a nivel sistema operativo y su manejo de memoria, en donde C++ al no tener Garbage collector, el sistema operativo te puede asignar un espacio de memoria, el cual al volver a ejecutar sea el mismo por ende tomas las variables en las mismas posiciones y su contenido va a seguir igual (No hubo otros procesos que pisen esta memoria).

Resumiendo, es tu responsabilidad la inicialización de variables, y cualquier otro escenario que contemples será manejado por el compilador y/o el sistema operativo como estos crean mejor que se tendría que manejar, siempre arbitrariamente.